# Change from vertical to horizontal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to web design so bear with me.

I have a simple sticky menu that sticks to the top of the page when the user scrolls down.
Its centered vertical at the minute and I'm trying to get in centered horizontal with not much luck. Been messing about with the widths but still no good.

Can anyone help please

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offsetTop;

    function scroll () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
            $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
            $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }
    }

    document.onscroll = scroll;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><center><a href="#">About Me</a></center></li>
        <li><center><a href="#">My Work</a></center></li>
        <li><center><a href="#">Experience</a></center></li>
        <li><center><a href="#">Contact Me</a></center></li>           
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {font-family:arial; margin:0; padding:0;}
.logo {font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;color:#a00; font-style:italic;}
.intro {color:#777; font-style:italic; margin:10px 0;}
.menu { color:#fff;   height:50px; line-height:30px;letter-spacing:1px; width:100%;}
.content {margin-top:10px;}
.menu-padding {padding-top:40px;}
.content p {margin-bottom:20px;}
.sticky {position:fixed; top:0;}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working demo?  (see http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Dont know what happened with the html bit and now I cant edit it but its in <div class="menu"> and each line looks like this <li><center><a href="#">About Me</a></center></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `li{
display:inline-block;
}` your menu should be horizontal.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7beu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `display` property to the css code: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8T9mh/)**

```
.menu ul li { display:inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the inline CONTENT of a `<div>` or any other block container, use `text-align: center`

To center a block CONTAINER in relation to its block parent, use `margin: 0 auto;`

You can try centering the `<ul>` as well:

```
.menu ul { width:140px, margin: 0 auto; } // Centering the UL in relation to menu
.menu ul li { text-align: center; } // Centering the text inside each <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `li{ display:inline-block; }` and some other properties on the menu you can get a menu with text centered and same whidth li , like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/P9533/2/